# How to test with Mocha and Chai express route

Tags: express, mocha.js, chai

I'm working on express app that render views with some data filtered.

My route is currently:

```
router.get('/user/name/:name', (req, res) => {
    return serverUtil.getUserByName(req.params.name).then(success =>{
        res.render('partials/users/user', {user: success});
    }).catch(err =>{
        res.render('partials/users/user', {error: err});
    });
});
```

As you may saw above, I'm sending a res.render but I don't know How to test it.

My Mocha test is currently like:

```
  it('Should post to user/name/:name', function(done){
    chai.request('http://localhost:5050')
      .get('/user/name/Britney')
      .end((err, res) => {
          console.log("res ", res.body); // empty
          exp(res).to.be.a('object');
          done();
        });
  });
```

But if I change the route for:

```
router.get('/user/name/:name', (req, res) => {
    return serverUtil.getUserByName(req.params.name).then(success =>{
        res.send({user: success}); //Change this
    }).catch(err =>{
        res.render('partials/users/user', {error: err});
    });
});
```

The test works as expected, but the application not.

So How I can test the route with the res.render, and the data that I passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out my problem.

First is necessary to use cheerio for this. So in the `res` parameter at `.end()` callback I'm getting the HTML in `res.text`. I was wrong looking for at res.body the code will be:

```
  it('Should post to user/name/:name', function(done){
    chai.request('http://localhost:5050')
      .get('/user/name/Britney')
      .end((err, res) => {
          res.should.have.status(200);

          exp(res).to.be.a('object');

          let $ = cheerio.load(res.text);
          let textid = $('#textid').val(); //the id of my id field

          exp(textid).to.have.equal('a0ece5db-cd14-4f21-812f-966633e7be86'); //true
          done();
        });
  });
```